# AWS EC2 instance is not connecting with terminal via SSH command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, putty

Whenever I try to connect my [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) EC2 instance via terminal using ssh command it shows a connection time-out problem.

One more thing, the public IP of that instance is not opening in a new tab, even after adding HTTP and HTTPS protocol in the inbound rule in the security group... Haven't found the solution til now. If you have any ideas/recommendations, share them in the comments below.

I changed the region to check if it was a problem in my region or not. But still showing the same thing. Checked my security group even..
Added HTTP and HTTPS in inbound rules but still public IP is not visible. I tried connecting via putty, but it still, didn't work.

[image: Photo of inbound rules]

Comment: SSH is not HTTP nor HTTPS. It has different port number, 22.

Comment: The instance will only respond to HTTP/S requests if you have installed a web server on the instance. What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I created a key-pair .pem file and tried to connect from there.. In the configuration, I added http and https in the inbound rule..

Comment: @Marcin yeah I know. I said, can't connect via ssh and can't open my instance's public ip in another tab. Both are different question.

Comment: Please show us the configuration of your Security Group. Did you add an Inbound rule for port 22 (SSH)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein https://i.stack.imgur.com/npjrP.png here it is.

Comment: And what is the `Source` column set to for those rules?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it's 0.0.0.0/0 for all

Comment: Have you _ever_ managed to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, was it in the same VPC, subnet and with the same security group? What is the command you are using to connect? Is it a Linux instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yeah it's a Linux instance. And the funny thing is sometimes it's getting connected (once in a blue moon) and sometimes not. I am using that ssh <key-pair filename>command with username and all the stuff. Just copying and pasting the same thing. Also, the public IP is not opening, even after adding HTTP and HTTPS in inbound rule. Do I have to do something more to see the IP live in the browser?

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS is irrelevant for SSH. The instance will only respond to HTTP/S traffic if you have installed a web server on the instance. If you are saying that you can _sometimes_ SSH into the instance, then the network configurations must be correct. It might be your network that is acting strangely. Try connecting via another network (eg home vs office vs tethered via your phone).

Answer (score 2):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using when establishing the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)